# How to link to a tag in a tag snippet?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt

This is probably a dupe, but I can't find the answer in the first few pages on google: how can I link to a tag in another tag snippet? `[tag:<something>]` doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I'd consider renaming the old question since it's hard to find the way it's titled. Also it links to a [now] non-existing tag as example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpts do not allow formatting of any kind. The standard for referencing another tag in an excerpt is to just use the square brackets, eg [analog-computer].